# Firestore copy function, copies only 1 document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 collections with the same structure and I want to copy the documents from one to the other. When I run it for the first time it copies one of the items, and if then I run it for multiple more times it doesn't copy anything more.

```
exports.copyDocs = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    let terminalIdToCopy = `123`; // terminal to be copied
    let terminalId = `456`; // terminal for the copies to be added

    let docsToCopy = db.collection(`/terminal/${terminalIdToCopy}/folderA/`);
    let docsNewDir = db.collection(`/terminal/${terminalId}/folderB/`);

    docsToCopy.get().then(snapshot => {
        let result = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            result.push(doc.data());
            let promise = docsNewDir.doc(doc.id).set(doc.data())
        });
        response.status(200).send(`Copied items: ${JSON.stringify(result)}. From terminal ${terminalIdToCopy} to terminal ${terminalId}`);
    }).catch(error => {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${error}`);
    });
});
```

I've also tried adding a .then (the log messages are not printed):

```
docsNewDir.doc(doc.id).set(doc.data())
            .then( i => { console.log(`i (${i})`)}, i2 => { console.log(`i2: ${i2}`);})
                .catch(error =>
                console.log(`Could NOT copy doc with id ${doc.id}: ${error}`)
            );
```

And I've also tried combining all the promises:

```
docsToCopy.get().then(snapshot => {
        let result = [];
        let promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            result.push(doc.data());
            promises.push(docsNewDir.doc(doc.id).set(doc.data()));
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then(values => {console.log("all done")});  // this won't print
        response.status(200).send(`Copied items: ${JSON.stringify(result)}. From terminal ${terminalIdToCopy} to terminal ${terminalId}`);
    }).catch(error => {
        response.status(500).send(`Error: ${error}`);
    });
```

The `result` contains all of the documents that should have been copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with using Promise.all(), but your final solution still needs to send the response only **after** all the promises resolve.  What you have now still sends the response before anything is fully resolved, which terminates the function before they can complete.  You should be doing something more like this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log("all done")
    response.status(200).send(`Copied items: ${JSON.stringify(result)}. From terminal ${terminalIdToCopy} to terminal ${terminalId}`);
});
```